# get id of the record inserted in database with one query

Tags: sql, linq

I insert a record using LINQ into the database. 
The database automaticaly inserts an ID for the record. But I need the Id which was given to the record to pass it to the client. Of course I can obtain the ID with another query. But can I do them both with one trip to the database?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an id property on your object the id property will be updated with the new id automatically.

Comment: Indeed, and this is true for both linq-to-sql and linq-to-entities in my experience, FWIW.